# Can I Embed a Contact Form within a Contact Form Using Contact Form 7 in Wordpress

Tags: plugins

I am looking to see if it is possible to embed one contact form within another on Wordpress using Contact Form 7.

Basically I have a competion that requires a user to Tick an Answer then enter there contact info so I want to create Form that asks the question then when I hit submit the user is presented with a Contact Form Pop Out that asks for the contact information. When this is submited the answer and the contact info is then posted.

Hope someone has had this before and found a resolution.

Look forward to hearing from you guys

Answer (score 0):

Could you use something like:

https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-conditional-fields/

to show the contact info fields only if the checkbox is checked?